# jquery ui autocomplete open event not firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using the jQuery UI Autocomplete plugin.

Everything is working fine but I would like to add a box in the end saying "Find more results".

I am trying to use the built-in `open` event to append the box into the opened `<ul>`, but the event never fires (the autocomplete list opens and is fully functional, the only problem is that the open event never fires.)

My code looks like this:

```
        $( "#q" ).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(userFriends, request.term);
                response(results.slice(0, 4));
            },
            minLength: 2,
            appendTo: '.searchbox',
            select: function (event, ui){
                window.location.href = '/u/'+ ui.item.value;
                return false;
            },
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                return false;
            },
            open: function (event, ui){
                console.log("AutoComplete Opened");
            }
        })

        .data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
            return $('<li>')
                .data('item.autocomplete', item)
                .append(
                '<a>' +
                    '<div>' +
                    '<div><img src="' + item.img + '" alt="" width="50" onerror="onErrorFixProfileImage(this)"/></div>' +
                    '<div>' + item.label + '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</a>'
            )
            .appendTo(ul);
        };
```

Does anyone know about reasons that this event will not fire?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried with alert inside your open event

Comment: Yes, I've tried with alerts, logs and jquery. Its just does not fire..

Comment: it does fire in my case http://jsfiddle.net/9Agqm/7/

Comment: yeah, it worked for me on other places too. but in this case, nothing happens. It might be related to something else, I just dont know what to look for...

Comment: see this,i used a bear minimum version of your code http://jsfiddle.net/9Agqm/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A late update,
I had a plugin installed called jquery.dimensions, it caused many issues with jquery-ui methods.
Removing it resolved the problem

Answer (score 1):

As a test, have you tried binding the event outside of the plugin initialisation? E.g:

```
$( "#q" ).on( "autocompleteopen", function( event, ui ) {
    console.log("AutoComplete Opened");
} );
```

## Edit

You could try prevent default in the other events instead of returning false:

```
select: function (event, ui){
    window.location.href = '/u/'+ ui.item.value;
    event.preventDefault();
},
focus: function (event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault();
},
```

Comment: Tried that just now... nothing happens,
I don't even get an error, just no response

Comment: Thanks for the help,
I replaced my returns but still no response.
I check all the other events and they all work fine. Only the open event is dead.
I think that I have something stopping it somewhere else in my site. Maybe you know what it can be??

Comment: Now I'm getting the following error in my console:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined"
can it be related?

Comment: in the jquery.js:

if ( document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle ) {
 getComputedStyle = function( elem, name ) {
  var ret, defaultView, computedStyle, width,
   style = elem.style;

  name = name.replace( rupper, "-$1" ).toLowerCase();

  if ( (defaultView = elem.ownerDocument.defaultView) &&
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined
    (computedStyle = defaultView.getComputedStyle( elem, null )) ) {

   ret = computedStyle.getPropertyValue( name );

Answer (score 0):

I have tested a simplified autocomplete adding your `open` method. It works fine, and the messages are correctly written in the console:

```
(function(){
    var aTags = ['java', 'javascript', 'actionscript', 'typescript', 'jscript', 'vbscript'];
    $('#tags').autocomplete({
        delay: 50
        , source:aTags
        , select: function(event, data){
            var $p = $('<p></p>').html(data.item.value).css({'display': 'inline-block', 'background-color': '#a0a0a0', 'color': '#ff0000'});
            $(event.target).after($p);
        }
        , open: function (event, ui){
            console.log("AutoComplete Opened");
        }
    });
})()​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xG7nR/1/).

Comment: Thanks, I know it works, but for some reason, mine doesn't...
Do you know about anything that might override it?